# Click a link and go to that page? How can I do this in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<a href="/wordpress/about" >About</a>
```

Click this link, it will load the /wordpress/about.php or any particular page inside theme directory, how can I do it in wordpress?

Comment: Same way you did it there - make a link, put in the URL.

Comment: @ceejayoz do you mean? href="/wordpress/about.php" ?

Comment: localhost/wordpress/about.php "page not found" error

Comment: The requested URL /wordpress/about.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Well, yeah, the page has to exist. `about` and `about.php` are different, and we don't know where on your server you put things.

Comment: I put about.php and used href="/wordpress/about.php" , still same error

Answer (score 0):

Click a link and go to that page 
Example: `<a href="#">Home</a>`